# How to prevent CSRF attacks when a CRUD action uses a link instead of a form?

Tags: security, csrf

I have implemented CSRF protection on my website using a CSRF token in a hidden input field in my forms. However at some places in my website I don't use a form for certain actions, e.g. a user can click a link to delete something (e.g. `/post/11/delete`). Currently this is open to a CSRF attack, so I want to implement a prevention for these links. How can I do this? I can think of two possible ways:

1. Make all links (which for example delete something) into tiny forms with only one hidden field (the CSRF token) and one submit button (styled as a normal link).
2. Add the CSRF token to the query-string

I don't like either of those options:

1. Styling a submit button to act exactly as a link might have some issues getting it correct (cross platform)?
2. Although it will never be picked up by search engines and don't like some random string in my URL (just aesthetics).

So is there a way I'm overlooking or are those two my options?

Comment: You shouldn’t use GET for actions with side effects but POST instead.

Comment: @Gumbo How would I do a `POST` request when making the request in a link??? E.g. Click [here](http://example.com/post/11/delete) to delete this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want URL parameters with long random values, you could implement a confirmation page for each Delete action, and have a form with your hidden field there.
Requests received at /post/11/delete without valid token will make the server respond with the confirmation page.
Requests received at /post/11/delete with valid token will trigger the deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [**token**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to your links.

---

1. styling submit to look like link is not hard. Though there will be issues with middle click or 'copy link location' command. Obviously.
2. facebook / google are not afraid of putting 'random strings' in urls. Neither should you. (Adding nofollow to those links, and excluding them in robots.txt should solve your fears with SEO. That is in case you for some reason *show REST links to guest users / search engines*).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to not perform updates via a GET operation.

Here's a clever little script that will hook into all of your links and make them POST a single hidden variable in addition to the payload in the querystring.  Hope this is helpful!

```
document.ready = function () {
    var makeLinkPost = function(link) {
        var handleClick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("<form action='" + this.href + "' method='POST'><input type='hidden' value='CSRF'/></form>'").appendTo("body").submit();
        }
        $(link).click(handleClick);
    }

    $("a").each(function() {
        makeLinkPost(this);
    })
}
```